# Cant Connect to AWS RDS using My Ip, but can using Anywhere

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, vpc

I am using AWS Aurora MySQL. I want to be able to connect to it locally using MySQL workbench.

The database cluster is set to be Public, and is within a VPN that has a public internet gateway. I know that this works because if I set the inbound rule of my Security Group to "All traffic, Anywhere", I can connect to it.

Obviously I don't want my database to be publicly accessible outside of a few IPs, so I have tried using the My IP option. It doesn't work. The connection times out. I have also tried providing a CIDR with a wade range (that should include my IP), but that didn't work either.

Is there any reason why creating an inbound rule for All Traffic, My IP wouldn't work, but creating an inbound rule for All Traffic, Anywhere would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With "All Traffic" temporarily allowed in the security group, connect to the database and run the query `SELECT USER();`.

Your IP address when making a connection to the database may differ from your IP address used for web browsing, if your network or your ISP has any kind of web proxy inline.  The `USER()` function should identify the correct IP address to use.

No other explanation seems likely, since you are able to connect with the security group allowing "all."

Comment: That was the issue. Thank you very much! I never would have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

This is often caused by a corporate firewall. For example, at my company port 5432 (Postgres) is blocked, so I need to use an SSH tunnel when connecting to our test databases from the office.

Answer (score 0):

To add to others' answers:

mysqld blocks a host after too many connection errors. The docs provide multiple ways to unblock a host: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html#blocked-host

Exactly what message you see probably depends on your MySQL ver:

- "Host 'host_name' is blocked because of many connection errors." - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/host-cache.html#host-cache-flushing
- "blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'" - https://serverfault.com/questions/530663/aws-rds-mysql-block-host-due-to-many-connections